# Allow default action for target event and prevent default action for parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have this kind of markup:

```
<a href="#">
   <input type="file" />
</a>
```

By default when you click on **input** "Select file" window appears and location changes to "#". How do I prevent browser from changing location?

What I have tried:

```
//location still changes
$('input').bind('click', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

//prevents "Select file" window
$('input').bind('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});

//prevents "Select file" window 
$('a').bind('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: just do `e.stopPropagation()` or `e.preventDefault()` - no need to wrap the event object with jQuery

Comment: But it doesn't hurt, does it?

Comment: yes it will - it will throw an error in the console as @Anton stated in his answer

Comment: Sorry, it is just a type, in fact I did like you said. So the problem still remains.

Comment: did you put it on the `$('a').click(function()` ?

Comment: I just created a html file on my desktop - same html setup as yours - preventDefault() on the anchor click and the hash tag doesn't show so it should work

Comment: Did the same, i'm not getting any hash tag either. Could be cache problems?

Comment: try <a href="javascript:void(0);">

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `$(e)` to `e.`

```
e.preventDefault();
```

When doing `$(e).preventDefault()` causes error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'preventDefault'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the user has clicked on the `a` element and not the input file. This should work.

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('a')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gf9EQ/3/)**